# Numpy Two-Dimensional Moving Average

Tags: python, numpy, moving-average

I have a 2d numpy array. I want to take the average value of the n nearest entries to each entry, just like taking a sliding average over a one-dimensional array. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: How do you define "n nearest entries"? Is this a square region centered on the current entry (eg 5x5)?

Comment: @PeterGibson That would work fine-- the exact shape of the region doesn't matter for my use case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a similar concept to applying a *filter* to an *image*.

Fortunately, [`scipy.ndimage.filters`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.filters) has a bunch of functions to do that. The one you're after is [`scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html).

Can be used like this:

```
a
=> 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])

uniform_filter(a, size=3, mode='constant')
=> 
array([[  1.33333333,   2.33333333,   3.        ,   3.66666667,          2.66666667],
       [  3.66666667,   6.        ,   7.        ,   8.        ,          5.66666667],
       [  7.        ,  11.        ,  12.        ,  13.        ,          9.        ],
       [ 10.33333333,  16.        ,  17.        ,  18.        ,         12.33333333],
       [  8.        ,  12.33333333,  13.        ,  13.66666667,          9.33333333]])
```

If you want a 5x5 filter, use `size=5`. The `mode` option controls how the edges are treated. You didn't specify how you want to handle the edges.  In this example, the "constant" mode means it treats each item outside the bounds of the array as a constant value of 0 (0 is the default, which can be overridden).

Comment: Thanks, but the linked documentation is a little sparse. What would be the exact call I would use if my image is called `img` and I want to calculate the average of a 5x5 grid around each pixel?

Comment: It's a bummer you can't specify a different `mode` for each axis.  Or, wait, I guess that wouldn't work.