# creates matlab average filter in python

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, numpy

there are functions in matlab for take the average value of the n nearest entries to each entry.

```
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])
```

creates average filter in matlab:

```
x=[[0.1,0.8,.2],
   [0.5,0.2,nan],
   [0.7,0.2,0.9],
   [0.4,0.7,1],
   [nan,0.14,1]]

fspecial('average',[3,3])
filter2(ave1,x)

[[ 0.17777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.27777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.3                nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan  0.43777778]
 [        nan         nan  0.31555556]]
```

I want to convert this to python.
I have found this: 
[uniform filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000260/numpy-two-dimensional-moving-average)
and:
[skimage.filters.rank.mean](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.filters.rank.html#skimage.filters.rank.mean)

but the result is not same as matlab. uniform filter:

```
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])

print(uniform_filter(x, size=3, mode='constant'))

[[ 0.17777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.27777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.3                nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan         nan]]
```

skimage filter:

```
from skimage.filters.rank import mean
from skimage.morphology import square
from skimage import img_as_float
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
        [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
        [0.7,0.2,0.9],
        [0.4,0.7,1],
        [np.nan,0.14,1]])

print(mean(x, square(3)))

[[102  76  76]
 [106 102  97]
 [114 130 127]
 [ 90 142 167]
 [ 79 137 181]]

print(img_as_float(mean(x, square(3))))

[[ 0.4         0.29803922  0.29803922]
 [ 0.41568627  0.4         0.38039216]
 [ 0.44705882  0.50980392  0.49803922]
 [ 0.35294118  0.55686275  0.65490196]
 [ 0.30980392  0.5372549   0.70980392]]
```

finally I have to it myself but is not mature in performance:

```
x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])



Winsize=3
adder=int(Winsize/2)
result=np.zeros_like(x)
nan_window_index=np.array([])
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        top_left_r= int(i-adder)
        top_left_c= int(j-adder)
        bottom_right_r=int(i+adder)
        bottom_right_c=int(j+adder)
        sum_list=np.array([])

        for r_counter in range(top_left_r, bottom_right_r+1):
            if r_counter<0 or r_counter > x.shape[0]-1:
                continue
            for c_counter in range(top_left_c, bottom_right_c+1):
                if c_counter<0 or c_counter > x.shape[1]-1:
                    continue
                if not np.isnan(x[r_counter, c_counter]):
                    sum_list=np.append(sum_list, x[r_counter, c_counter])
                else:
                    nan_window_index=np.append(nan_window_index, [[r_counter, c_counter]])

        result[i,j]= np.sum(sum_list)/(Winsize*Winsize)

nan_window_index=np.unique(nan_window_index.reshape(int(len(nan_window_index)/2),2), axis=0)

for i,j in nan_window_index:
    top_left_r= int(i-adder)
    top_left_c= int(j-adder)
    bottom_right_r=int(i+adder)
    bottom_right_c=int(j+adder)

    for r_counter in range(top_left_r, bottom_right_r+1):
        if r_counter<0 or r_counter > x.shape[0]-1:
            continue
        for c_counter in range(top_left_c, bottom_right_c+1):
            if c_counter<0 or c_counter > x.shape[1]-1:
                continue
            result[r_counter, c_counter]=np.nan

print(result)
```

and the result is same as matlab:

```
[[ 0.17777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.27777778         nan         nan]
 [ 0.3                nan         nan]
 [        nan         nan  0.43777778]
 [        nan         nan  0.31555556]]
```

any suggestion for  better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scipy.signal.convolve` (or perhaps `scipy.signal.convolve2d` as it might be quicker) as:

```
import numpy as np
# from scipy.signal import convolve
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

x=np.array([[0.1,0.8,.2],
            [0.5,0.2,np.nan],
            [0.7,0.2,0.9],
            [0.4,0.7,1],
            [np.nan,0.14,1]])

core = np.full((3,3),1/3**2)

# convolve(x, core, mode='same')
convolve2d(x, core, mode='same')
```

Convolution with uniform values is the same as a uniform filter. Note that this will automatically "assume" zeros outside your matrix, but that is in line with what you are asking for, so it will work in your current setup.