# Numpy find average of every 2x2 array inside a large array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a 6x6 numpy array

From this I want to find the average of every 2x2 array inside the large 6x6 array.
Like:

```
array= 
[10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 15
 34, 56, 67, 34, 45, 91
 23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44
 10, 20, 30, 12, 15, 15
 34, 56, 67, 11, 10, 91
 23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44]


set1= 
[10, 20
34, 56]  Average=30

set2=
[20, 30
56, 67]  Average=43

....
....

setN=
[10, 91
34, 44]  Average=44
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Regardless of the answers already given, you need to post your attempt at solving the problem and not expect people to write code for you.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you want to calculate the 2D [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of your array, with a 2x2 window. This can be done by convolution, [scipy.signal.convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) can calculate a 2D convolution.

First, you should define your array to actually be 2D:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(
[[10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 15],
 [34, 56, 67, 34, 45, 91],
 [23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44],
 [10, 20, 30, 12, 15, 15],
 [34, 56, 67, 11, 10, 91],
 [23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44]])
```

Then do a 2D convolution using [scipy.signal.convolve2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html):

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

# create an averaging kernel
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), dtype=float)
kernel /= kernel.size

# compute 2d moving average
conv = convolve2d(arr, kernel, mode='valid')
print(conv[0][0]) # 30.
```

If you want to get the result as `dtype=int`, do:

```
conv = conv.astype(int)
```

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000260/numpy-two-dimensional-moving-average).

Comment: Sorry, please ask your questions here. If this is too advanced, you should find a simpler solution you can understand yourself.

Comment: I added some more links to related topics to help you further.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `skimage.util.shape.view_as_windows`:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
array = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 15],
                 [34, 56, 67, 34, 45, 91],
                 [23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44],
                 [10, 20, 30, 12, 15, 15],
                 [34, 56, 67, 11, 10, 91],
                 [23, 87, 56, 90, 34, 44]])
```

My implementiation:

```
b = view_as_windows(array, window_shape=(2, 2), step=1)

np.array(list(map(lambda x: [np.mean(i) for i in x], b)))
```

Result:

```
array([[30.  , 43.25, 37.75, 34.75, 47.75],
       [50.  , 66.5 , 61.75, 50.75, 53.5 ],
       [35.  , 48.25, 47.  , 37.75, 27.  ],
       [30.  , 43.25, 30.  , 12.  , 32.75],
       [50.  , 66.5 , 56.  , 36.25, 44.75]])
```

Comment: Your step size is too large, you should only move by one step, not by two.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
m, n = 2, 2

avgs = [
    array[x:x+m,y:y+n].mean()
    for x in range(array.shape[0]-m) 
    for y in range(array.shape[1]-n)
]
```

This will raster across your array collecting the average value in the MxN subarrays

Comment: `min(avgs)` but you really should show an attempt at solving this yourself when you ask a question, otherwise it's [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AdarshBabu You can use the logic here to create a function that stores (m, n) if it's the current lowest value, then return (m, n) once done